# import csv matrix to create a weighted and directed network in networkx python

Tags: python, networkx

I am new to python and networkx. 
How can I create a directed and weighted network by importing a weights adjacency matrix in csv format (see below for a 2*2 example)?

```
 3.4, 1.2,
 0.8, 1.3,
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least two options: You can read such a file directly into a numpy array using [`numpy.loadtxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html#numpy.loadtxt). Maybe that is all you need since you might want to use the matrix to perform linear algebra operations on it.

If you need a directed network you can then simply initialize a graph from it with [networkx.from_numpy_matrix](http://networkx.github.io/documentation/latest/reference/generated/networkx.convert.from_numpy_matrix.html):

```
adj_mat = numpy.loadtxt(filename)
net = networkx.from_numpy_matrix(adj_mat, create_using=networkx.DiGraph())
```

```
net.edges(data=True)
```

```
[(0, 0, {'weight': 3.4}),
 (0, 1, {'weight': 1.2}),
 (1, 0, {'weight': 0.8}),
 (1, 1, {'weight': 1.3})]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. But the "net" generated will be automatically edge-weighted?

Comment: Yes, it would. `mat = np.array([[1,2],[2,1]])`, `G.adj --> {0: {0: {'weight': 1}, 1: {'weight': 2}},
 1: {0: {'weight': 2}, 1: {'weight': 1}}}`